# Functions in postgres SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I have this query that works, but I need help to put it into a function and make the dates variable. I would love some help since I'm not that good at fuctions .

```
SELECT equipo.nombre
    ,e3.nombre
    ,e2.nombre
    ,e1.nombre
    ,tpe.tiempo_inicio::TIMESTAMP (0) AS "Tiempoini"
    ,LEAD(tpe.tiempo_inicio) OVER (
        ORDER BY equipo.id, tpe.tiempo_inicio ASC
        )::TIMESTAMP (0) AS "tiempofin"
    ,LEAD(tpe.tiempo_inicio::TIMESTAMP (0)) OVER (
        ORDER BY equipo.id
        ) - tpe.tiempo_inicio::TIMESTAMP (0) AS "diferencia"
FROM tp_estados tpe
LEFT JOIN ts_equipos equipo ON tpe.id_equipo = equipo.id
LEFT JOIN ts_detal_estado e1 ON tpe.id_detal_estado = e1.id
LEFT JOIN ts_detal_estado e2 ON e1.id_tipo_estad = e2.id
LEFT JOIN ts_detal_estado e3 ON e2.id_tipo_estad = e3.id
WHERE equipo.id = 356
AND tpe.tiem_creac BETWEEN '2020-01-22 11:14:02' AND '2020-01-22 12:30:08' //this dates have to be variable
AND e1.isestado = true
```

Comment: Use a function with `LANGUAGE sql`. Then you can simply use your query and replace the constants with the function parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `function_name` to something meaningful and define the columns that are being returned.

```
CREATE FUNCTION function_name(start_date timestamp, end_date timestamp)
  RETURNS table(...) //DEFINE YOUR COLUMNS
AS $$
SELECT equipo.nombre
    ,e3.nombre
    ,e2.nombre
    ,e1.nombre
    ,tpe.tiempo_inicio::TIMESTAMP (0) AS "Tiempoini"
    ,LEAD(tpe.tiempo_inicio) OVER (
        ORDER BY equipo.id
            ,tpe.tiempo_inicio ASC
        )::TIMESTAMP (0) AS "tiempofin"
    ,lEAD(tpe.tiempo_inicio::TIMESTAMP (0)) OVER (
        ORDER BY equipo.id
        ) - tpe.tiempo_inicio::TIMESTAMP (0) AS "diferencia"
FROM tp_estados tpe
LEFT JOIN ts_equipos equipo ON tpe.id_equipo = equipo.id
LEFT JOIN ts_detal_estado e1 ON tpe.id_detal_estado = e1.id
LEFT JOIN ts_detal_estado e2 ON e1.id_tipo_estad = e2.id
LEFT JOIN ts_detal_estado e3 ON e2.id_tipo_estad = e3.id
WHERE equipo.id = 356
    AND tpe.tiem_creac BETWEEN start_date 
        AND end_date //this dates have to be variable
    AND e1.isestado = true
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```